# Normal frames, locally inertial frame and freely falling frame?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, metric-tensor

I am looking for the definition and the relation to the metric of the falling 3 types of frames:

1. Locally inertial frame
2. Freely falling frame
3. Normal frame (i.e. neither of the above)

Please can some explain these to me?

**My attempt at an explanation**

I provide this as a guide of the sort of thing I am looking for in an answer. *This may not be and probable isn't correct*.

From what I have read and tried to interpret. The following is true. In the case of $3$ the metric expanded about the location of the observer $\mathscr{X}^\mu$ is given by:
$$g_{\mu \nu}=\eta_{\mu \nu}+A_{\mu}(x^\mu-\mathscr{X}^\mu)+B_{\mu \nu}(x^\mu-\mathscr{X}^\mu)(x^\nu-\mathscr{X}^\nu)+...$$
where $A_\mu$ and $B_{\mu \nu}$ are constants and not necessarily tensors. This means that the laws of special relativity, which do not involve first derivatives, work for $x^\mu$ close to $\mathscr{X}^\mu$.

In the case of $2$ the metric tensor is:
$$g_{\mu \nu}=\eta_{\mu \nu}+B_{\mu \nu}(x^\mu-\mathscr{X}^\mu)(x^\nu-\mathscr{X}^\nu)+...$$
In which case the laws of special relativity, which involve derivatives up to the first, work for $x^\mu$ close to $\mathscr{X}^\mu$.

I do not know how to distinguish $1$ from $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the usage of the terms "freely falling frame" and "normal frame"? Do you mean [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates), also called locally flat coordinates?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think he meant normal as in "general", like, one without any special properties.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your Taylor expansion is incorrect. The first and second order terms have no free indices. Instead it should be

$$ g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+A_{\mu\nu,\alpha}(x^\alpha-x_0^\alpha)+B_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(x^\alpha-x_0^\alpha)(x^\beta-x^\beta_0)+..., $$
where the commas are **not** derivatives, just a device I used to separate the indices.

Secondly, "locally inertial frame" is a standard terminology, but "freely falling frame" isn't. With that said, in terms of meaning, the two are one and the same.

Your frame is inertial if $\Gamma=0$ in it, because the connection coefficients represent inertial forces. A frame is inertial if there are no inertial forces in it.

This rules out your first expansion. At point $p$, whose coordinates are $x^\mu_0$ (I took the liberty of using $x_0$ instead of your fancy calligraphic notation), the derivatives of the metric can be expressed as

$$ \left.\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\sigma}\right|_{x=x_0}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\sigma}(A_{\mu\nu,\alpha}(x^\alpha-x^\alpha_0))=A_{\mu\nu,\sigma}, $$
so
$$ \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}(x_0)=\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\lambda\rho}(A_{\nu\rho,\mu}+A_{\mu\rho,\nu}-A_{\mu\nu,\rho}), $$
which in general will not be zero.

So for a frame to be locally inertial/"freely falling", you need to have

$$ g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+B_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(x^\alpha-x^\alpha_0)(x^\beta-x^\beta_0)+... $$

I will note, however, that technically speaking, any coordinate system, in which the metric is expressible as
$$ g_{\mu\nu}=g^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}+B_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(x^\alpha-x^\alpha_0)(x^\beta-x^\beta_0)+..., $$
where $g^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}$ has **constant** coefficients is a locally inertial frame. In this case, this coordinate system at $x_0$ looks like an **oblique** coordinate system, not a rectangular cartesian one, but is still inertial. But in flat space/spacetime we are obsessed with cartesian coordinates, so this is often unmentioned.

**A potential source of confusion:**

When we mean a frame, we often mean a **coordinate frame**. A coordinate frame is a local coordinate system, which determines four local vector fields, in invariant notation often written as $\{\partial_\mu\}_{\mu=0}^3$, these vectors are linearly independent everywhere and commute.
The phrase "locally inertial frame" is meant in this sense.

On the other hand, when we talk about "general frames" or "orthonormal frames", we usually mean four locally defined, linearly independent vector fields, $\{e_0,...,e_3\}$, which serve as a basis for component expansions, but are completely independent from coordinate system (see "tetrad" or "vielbein" approach to GR). These frames usually do not commute, since if they did, they'd also form a coordinate system (in fact, *orthonormal* frames can commute only if spacetime is flat in their domain of definition).
So when you mean a "normal frame", I assume you mean a "totally general frame", it either refers to a totally general coordinate system, or a totally general non-coordinate (anholonomic) frame, I just described.

But you might be meaning *Riemann normal coordinates*, *affine normal coordinates*, *Fermi normal coordinates* or *Gauss normal coordinates* instead.

If so, Riemann normal coordinates are the same as locally inertial frames, affine normal coordinates are an equivalent constructions for manifolds without a metric, but who possess a linear connection (in this case, a coordinate system where the connection coefficients vanish at a point), Fermi normal coordinates are like Riemann normal coordinates, but the connection coefficients also vanish along a chosen geodesic, and Gauss normal coordinates is a coordinate system in which spacetime is split into a $3+1$ orthogonal decomposition along a hypersurface.